# Refresh data in react-native

Tags: react-native

Hi so I want to refresh data when I pull down but I'm not sure about how to do it. Here is my code :

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  async getData(){
    const url = "SomeUrl";
    await fetch(url) 
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: res
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("get data error:" + error);
    });
  }
```

```
 <SafeAreaView style={{ flex:1 }}>
     <View style={styles.main_container}>
        <FlatList style={styles.flatList}
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          extraData = {this.state}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.MembreId}
          renderItem={(item) => <UserItem user={item} displayDetailForUser={this._displayDetailForUser} />}
          numColumns={numColumns}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh} />
     </View>
 </SafeAreaView>
```

So here I'm getting the data in `dataSource`. I have tried this but it's loading endlessly.. And do I also need to wipe the previous data in `dataSource` first or not ?

```
handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState (
      {
        refreshing: true,
      },
      () => {
        setTimeout(() => {this.getData()}, 1000)
      }
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `refreshing` state to false in `this.getData()` with dataSource.

Comment: Thanks but how can I empty the dataSource then ? Do I have to empty it, wouldn't dataSource get too big if I'm not ?

Comment: You don't need to empty it. It will replace the dataSource and probably you don't need setTimeout also except if it's required for some other work.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not setting the refreshing back to false once the data comes back. Try this for getData:

```
async getData(){
  const url = "SomeUrl";
  await fetch(url) 
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      dataSource: res,
      refreshing: false,
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("get data error:" + error);
  });
}
```